# How do I change things in the Stable Diffusion WebUI html and scrips?

Tags: javascript, html, stable-diffusion

I'm still learning in the world of web development and would like to alter the WebUI of stable diffusion: https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui
I know it should be possible to change around or delete buttons etc, but I don't know where to start. Where is the HTML code located in this project? I can't seem to find it.
I appreciate any help!

Comment: There's a folder called `html` https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/tree/master/html is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Hi, I found that folder, but I can't find for example the "generate" button of the WebUI in it.

Comment: It doesn't seem to contain the UI

Comment: The UI looks to be generated with python https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/blob/394ffa7b0a7fff3ec484bcd084e673a8b301ccc8/modules/ui.py#L297

Comment: Ooh, I didn't know that was possible. Do you think I can modify the python code to make it generate differently? Thanks for the help btw!

Comment: I don't see why you can't. Sadly, I can't help with that